# Use Same Component as Multiple component with same nature , Using the title name of clicked component

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, url-routing, angular-routing

Suppose I have created a single component In an angular Project , and I have few more components with exactly same nature, I just don't want to create another components for them , Can I route different component through single path using menu-bar name (title)?
Like I have worked for TestComponent1 -----

(e.g)
http://localhost:4200/TestComponent1 I have complete work for it.

when I click to another component from menu Like clicked on TestComponent2 , I want to use the functionality of TestComponent1 in TestComponent2 , picking through menu-title Name.

I have tried with same route but it select all component in a same time , and picked the last title name selected

Comment: Hey Osama, not sure if it is just me but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could give us a working example on stackblitz and try to be a bit more specific. Thanks!

Comment: I am just trying to route same component with 2 or more different route path.